# How to add labels to the row index

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('Grade.txt',index_col=0,header=None)
>>> print(df)
          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0                                               
Sarah K.  10   9   7   9  10  20  19  19  45  92
John M.    9   9   8   9   8  20  20  18  43  95
David R.   8   7   7   9   6  18  17  17  40  83
Joan A.    9  10  10  10  10  20  19  20  47  99
Nick J.    9   7  10  10  10  20  20  19  46  98
Vicki T.   7   7   8   9   9  17  18  19  44  88
>>> print(df.mean(axis=0))
1      8.666667
2      8.166667
3      8.333333
4      9.333333
5      8.833333
6     19.166667
7     18.833333
8     18.666667
9     44.166667
10    92.500000
```

Right now they are labeled 1-10 and I want the rows to look like this:

```
Homework #1        8.67
Homework #2        8.17
Homework #3        8.33
Homework #4        9.33
Homework #5        8.83
Quiz #1           19.17
Quiz #2           18.83
Quiz #3           18.67
Midterm #1        44.17
Final #1          92.50
```

I'm just looking for the right way to go about the labeling. So instead of 1-10 I'm looking for (Homework#1, Homework#2, Homework#3, etc.)  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent logic to derive the `column` names from the `column` number, you'll probably need label the `columns` with a simple `list` of the names:

```
cols

['Homework #1', 'Homework #2', 'Homework #3', 'Homework #4', 'Homework #5', 'Quiz #1', 'Quiz #2', 'Quiz #3', 'Midterm #1', 'Final #1']

df

          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0                                               
Sarah K.  10   9   7   9  10  20  19  19  45  92
John M.    9   9   8   9   8  20  20  18  43  95
David R.   8   7   7   9   6  18  17  17  40  83
Joan A.    9  10  10  10  10  20  19  20  47  99
Nick J.    9   7  10  10  10  20  20  19  46  98
Vicki T.   7   7   8   9   9  17  18  19  44  88


df.columns = cols
df.mean()

Homework #1     8.666667
Homework #2     8.166667
Homework #3     8.333333
Homework #4     9.333333
Homework #5     8.833333
Quiz #1        19.166667
Quiz #2        18.833333
Quiz #3        18.666667
Midterm #1     44.166667
Final #1       92.500000
```